can't adjust Chrome tab size in Noble Numbat Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
The other fonts seem to dynamically adjust correctly, but I can't adjust the Chrome (included stable distro relase version) tab size in Noble Numbat Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. I would like to make them much smaller. I noticed that in Ubuntu Tweaks, the ability to adjust the "Legacy Window Titles" setting is gone.

Well, I was able to make them smaller by changing the "Interface Text" size in the Ubuntu Tweaks app. The key is to log out for the changes to affect Chrome. Hopefully now I can scale up the Nautilus typeface size.
